# Avoid loading native libraries from system path

Tags: java, android

Our SDK requires one of two native libraries, say, `libaaa.so` and `libbbb.so`.

In our Java code, we wrote

```
private static boolean jniloaded = false;
static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("aaa");
        jniloaded = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        jniloaded = false;
    }
    if (!jniloaded) {
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("bbb");
            jniloaded = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            jniloaded = false;
        }
    }
}
```

With this snippet, the library load order is:

1. Load libaaa.so in app's library path
2. If 1 failed, load libaaa.so in system library path
3. If 2 failed too, load libbbb.so in app's library path
4. If 3 still failed, load libbbb.so in system path.

How can I reorder it to be:

1. Load libaaa.so in app's library path
2. If 1 failed, load libbbb.so in app's library path
3. If 2 failed too, load libaaa.so in system library path
4. If 3 still failed, load libbbb.so in system path.

without any knowledge about app's package name?

I tried to parse `System.getProperty("java.library.path")` to get the library paths and iterate `System.load()` by myself. However `System.getProperty("java.library.path")` does not contain the app's library path. It only contains system library path.

Comment: Discovering the package name at runtime is trivial, so that would not be a reason you cannot use the explicit-path System.load() instead.  However, I believe the default app library path has recently changed - probably with a simlink for backwards compatibility, but it does point to how depending on that may not be desirable.  How are you ending up needing to optionally override libraries anyway?  Are you attempting to directly utilize non-public system libraries?

Comment: @ChrisStratton It was due to different product packaging strategies. Somehow one customer "A" preloaded libaaa.so into /system/lib in some devices, and another customer "B" package their app with libbbb.so, and the /system/lib/libaaa.so is too old for customer "B"'s app.

Comment: By that description it sounds like you should be using an app-packaged libbbb first.  If that is missing there's no system path libbbb, so you'd next try a non-existent app-packaged libaaa, and finally a system-packaged libaaa?

Comment: @ChrisStratton In this scenario, yes. However I worry that there might be another customer making the symmetric scenario. In that case moving `System.loadLibrary("bbb")` before `System.loadLibrary("aaa")` does not work anymore.

Comment: It might be time to get a handle on things by giving your users clear rules, and inserting checks to break misbehaving ones immediately from the first developer test attempts.  Or maybe you should just start encoding SDK version in the library name, so you only get the right one - theoretically even in the unlucky case of two system apps which actually need different versions.